# Why AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks does not work in my data stream?

Tags: flink-streaming, flink-cep

I've some problem. 
I use .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new MyAssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks(60000)) in middle a programm (after some filters, map and other apache flink operators). 
I've simple Pattern:

```
begin("start", AfterMatchSkipStrategy.skipToLast("end"))
  .where(new SimpleConditionA())
  .followedBy("end")
  .where(new SimpleConditionB())
  .within(Times.minutes(5));
```

I read a messages from Apache kafka (below are the  event timestamps) 
Message A: A.timestamp = 11:50:00 
Message B: B.timestamp = 11:51:00

```
public class MyAssignerWithPunctuatedWatermark implements AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermark{

  private long maxOutOfOrderness;
  private long currentMaxTimestamp;
  /*there are a Constructor*/

  public long extractTimestamp (Event e, long l){
    long timestamp = e.timestamp;
    if(timestamp > currentMaxTimestamp){
      currentMaxTimestamp = timestamp;
    }
    return timestamp;
  }

  public Watermark checkAndGetNextWatermark(Event e, long l){
    return new Watermark(currentMaxTimestamp - maxOutOfOrderness);
  }
}
```

Then I put in Apache Kafka a Message A - it was OK! 
Then I put in Apache Kafka a Message B - and pattern was not assemled. (I use a logging journal in SimpleCondtionB, Message B does not go in SimpleCondtion). WHY???? 
When I used .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new IngestionTimeExtractor()). It was all ok. But I need to take a late (be late no more than 1 minutes) events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary that `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` is done *before* any operations that depend on timing. CEP depends on the timing information provided by `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` in order to sort the input stream, and to handle the `within(duration)` constraint.

In order to correctly match a Pattern against a possibly out-of-order event time stream, CEP must first sort the incoming events by their timestamps. As part of this, each incoming event is held in a buffer until the current watermark has passed its timestamp -- because up to that point, an earlier event might still arrive (without being considered *late*). Late events, with timestamps before the current watermark, are either dropped by CEP, or sent to a side output (if one is configured).

So, in order for Message B to be processed by your Pattern, you must first inject an event whose timestamp is enough later than 11:51:00 (the time of Message B) to satisfy the `maxOutOfOrderness` you've used in your watermark generator.

With an `IngestionTimeExtractor` the events can not be out-of-order, so this sorting step isn't needed, and Message B can be processed without delay.

Comment: David I use .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(.....), before Pattern. I haven't time operators before CEP.

Comment: Thanks David, I understand you, Today I had experiment with PunctuatedWatermarks and understand it was bad idea for me. I needed to immediately emit а message B.  It is'not possible with Punctuated or Periodic watermarks.